# Sampling Variability

Tags: probability, self-study

I want to study the effects of an organization-wide training program on a specific policy, in a company of 670 employees, designed to increase compliance with that policy.

1. Not all employees have been through this training, but all will eventually attend.
2. I would like to compare 50 employees who have not attended the training and 50 who have (sample of my population)
3. I want to distinguish whether the program is effective or whether the improvement is reasonably explained by sampling variation.
4. I would retrospectively analyze prospectively collected data, through internal policy compliance review mechanisms already in place.
5. I will collect pre- and post-test results on employees, who have attended the training.

So my null hypothesis: (Ho) As a result of the XYZ company employee training program, either there will be no significant difference in policy compliance or there will be a significant increase.

And alternative: (Ha) As a result of the XYZ company employee training program, there will be a significant increase in policy compliance.

Should I use nonprobability vs. probability sampling? I guess there is no real way I can randomly select employees...Can I just compare those who have attended the training and their compliance to the policy with the rest of the population? Where do I go from here?

Comment: Your null appears to include your alternative. Please clarify.

Comment: I guess my prediction is that compliance will increase, thus this would be a one-tailed hypothesis.